# Euler’s Characteristic for nonorientable surfaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

I recently learned about this in a topology class but wanted to know how to apply the Euler Characteristic for surfaces such as projective planes and Klein bottles (nonorientable surfaces).

I have come across a few proofs with different approaches for the Euler Characteristic for orientable surfaces where you start with $χ(Σ_g): = faces − edges + vertices = 2 − 2g. $

Following similar logic from those proofs, I tried to see if I could come up with a proof for nonorientable surfaces (mostly by using induction) and by starting with $χ(Σ_k): = 2 − k $

(from Wiki, don't quite understand why this is the way it is).

So, what would the proof for Euler’s Characteristic for nonorientable surfaces look like? Thanks.

...........

Comment: What exactly you are trying to prove here? That for non-orientable genus $k$ we have $\chi=2-k$?

Comment: Hint: Euler characteristic is multiplicative under covering maps. Now, use the fact that every nonorientable surface has an 2-fold orientable covering. Or, you may prefer to learn some homology theory.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: you could just choose a cellulation. Homology theory is overkill, although probably the best way to indicate well-definedness of $\chi$ in the first place.